eigenvalue of sparse symmetric tridiagonal block matrix with symmetric blocks
I am working on spectrum graph theory, and I got the Laplacian matrix of the special graph as the following block matrix:
$L(G)=
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   4I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & O &.... & O & O & O & O & O\\
   O &  4I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & .... & O & O & O & O & O\\
            -J & O &  4I_{2} & O & -J & .... & O & O & O & O & O\\
            O & -J & O & 4I_{2} & O & .... & -J & O & O & O & O\\
            O & O & -J & O & 4I_{2} & .... & O & -J & O & O & O\\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . & . & . &\\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . & . & . &\\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . & . & . &\\
            O & O & O & -J & O & .... & 4I_{2} & O & -J & O & O\\
            O & O & O & O & -J & .... & O & 4I_{2} & O & -J & O\\
            O & O & O & O & O & .... & -J & O & 4I_{2} & O & -J\\
            O & O & O & O & O & .... & O & -J & O & 4I_{2} & -J\\
            O & O & O & O & O & ....  & O & O & -J & -J & 4I_{2}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
where $J$ is a matrix of all ones of size 2, O is a zero matrix of size 2 and $I_{2}$ is an identity matrix of size 2.
The Laplacian matrix L(G) is of size n such that $n=pq$ for $p$ and $q$ are tow distinct prime integers and $p < q$. I need to find the eigenvalues of $L(G)$, so by using the eigenvalue equation we obtain the following matrix:
$L(G)-\lambda I_{n}=
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   (4-\lambda)I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & O &.... & O & O & O & O & O\\
   O &  (4-\lambda)I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & .... & O & O & O & O & O\\
            -J & O &  (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J & .... & O & O & O & O & O\\
            O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & .... & -J & O & O & O & O\\
            O & O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & .... & O & -J & O & O & O\\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . & . & . &\\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . & . & . &\\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . & . & . &\\
            O & O & O & -J & O & .... & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J & O & O\\
            O & O & O & O & -J & .... & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J & O\\
            O & O & O & O & O & .... & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J\\
            O & O & O & O & O & .... & O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & -J\\
            O & O & O & O & O & ....  & O & O & -J & -J & (4-\lambda)I_{2}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
To find eigenvalues of L(G) with multiplicities, I partitioned it to the following submatrices:
$L(G)-\lambda I_{n}=
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   M-\lambda I_{n-4} & N \\
   N^T &  Q-\lambda I_{4}
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
where $M-\lambda I_{n-4}=
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   (4-\lambda)I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & O &.... & O & O & O \\
   O &  (4-\lambda)I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & .... & O & O & O \\
            -J & O &  (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J & .... & O & O & O \\
            O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & .... & -J & O & O \\
            O & O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & .... & O & -J & O \\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . \\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . \\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . \\
            O & O & O & -J & O & .... & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J \\
            O & O & O & O & -J & .... & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O \\
            O & O & O & O & O & .... & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2}\\    
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
$N=\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   O & O \\
            O & O \\
            . & . \\
            . & . \\
            . & . &\\
   -J &  O \\
            O &  -J \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
and
$Q-\lambda I_{4}=\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   (4-\lambda)I_{2} &  -J \\
            -J &  (4-\lambda)I_{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
Since $Q-\lambda I_{4}$ is invertible submatrix, then by use Schur complement I got
$det(L(G)-\lambda I_{n})=det(Q-\lambda I_{4}) det((M-\lambda I_{n-4})-N(Q-\lambda I_{4})^{-1}N^T)$ where $det(Q-\lambda I_{4})=(4-\lambda)^2(6-\lambda)(2-\lambda)$ and
$((M-\lambda I_{n-4})-N(Q-\lambda I_{4})^{-1}N^T)=$
$\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   (4-\lambda)I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & O &.... & O & O & O \\
   O &  (4-\lambda)I_{2}-J & O & -J & O & .... & O & O & O \\
            -J & O &  (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J & .... & O & O & O \\
            O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & .... & -J & O & O \\
            O & O & -J & O & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & .... & O & -J & O \\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . \\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . \\
            . & . & .& . & . &                 . & . & .& . \\
            O & O & O & -J & O & .... & (4-\lambda)I_{2} & O & -J \\
            O & O & O & O & -J & .... & O & (4-\lambda)(I_{2}-2J) & O \\
            O & O & O & O & O & .... & -J & O & (4-\lambda)(I_{2}-2J)\\    
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}$
I need an easy analytical method to find $det((M-\lambda I_{n-4})-N(Q-\lambda I_{4})^{-1}N^T)$ to obtain general eigenvalues of $L(G)$, or any other method better than of my method. Thanks
